# how to insert content before each new line using CSS

Tags: css

I have a HTML document that looks like the following, and using only CSS I want to insert an asterisk before each line. For the first line, the following works:

```css
p:before {
  content: "*";
}
```

```html
<p>
  test
  <br> test2
  <br> test3
</p>
```

but I don't know how to add the asterisk before each subsequent line.
I've tried:

```css
p:before {
  content: "*";
}

p>br:after {
  content: "*";
}
```

```html
<p>
  test
  <br> test2
  <br> test3
</p>
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I accomplish this?

codepen: https://codepen.io/ds241/pen/QWQyPKY

Comment: Please provide example code here on Stack Overflow. See [ask], where it notes "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Comment: Why not use list elements instead for what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen i am not able to edit the html for this case.

Comment: @nylki Are you able to run custom scripts?

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen yes I can

Comment: @nylki Can you share the structure of your document (the HTML file), so I can see how to appropriately  select this `p` element. Ofcourse, you do not want my script to modify all the paragraphs on your site.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen the lines are separated by <br> in a div with class "quote".

`<div class="quote">line1<br>line2<br>line3</div>`

Comment: If you were accepting JavaScript answers add the tag.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you select this div with class `quote`, extract its `innerHTML`, and convert it to a string with the `toString()` method. You then split this string with `<br>` separater, which results in an array. You then map this array to include a `*` before the start of each new line word.

Finally, you join this array together using the same `<br>` separator, and set the `innerHTML` of your `quote` to this. The code ends up looking like this.

```
const quote = document.querySelector(".quote");
let innerHTML = quote.innerHTML;

const t = innerHTML.toString();
let s = t.split("<br>");
s = s.map((i) => {
  return `*${i}`;
});
s = s.join("<br>");
quote.innerHTML = s;
```

Comment: thank you, this works. since it isn't possible to do what i originally asked, i will mark this as the answer.

Comment: Good luck my friend! As I mentioned in another comment, there is only so much you can do with CSS alone (`::first-letter`, and `::first-line`) To do more than that, you will need to plugin JavaScript sooner or later :)

Comment: @nylki it is possible with CSS. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72165919/2813224)

Answer (score 0):

### Two ways to Make a Line Break with Unicode

First assign the following CSS:

**Figure I**

```css
p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

The above applies to both techniques. The first way is to use `&#10;` in HTML.

**Figure II**

```html
<p>test1&#10;test2&#10;test3&#10;</p>
```

The second way is to use `::before`, `content`, and `\00000a`.

**Figure III**

```css
p::before {
  content: "\00002a test1\00000a \00002a test2\00000a \00002a test3\00000a";
}
```

```css
p {
  white-space: pre
}

.a::before {
  content: "\00002a test1\00000a \00002a test2\00000a \00002a test3\00000a";
}
```

```html
<p class='a'></p>

<p>
*test4&#10;*test5&#10;*test6&#10;
</p>
```

Comment: OP claims that he is unable to edit the HTML file.

Comment: See figure III. It requires an element, I assume there's an element in OP's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This is because all your content is inside one element. And with the pseudo-selector, you can only target the element, not its content.

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
let res = document.querySelector('.res');
res.innerText = p.innerText;
```

```html
<p>
  test
  <br> test2
  <br> test3
</p>

<div class="res"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to wrap each of the lines of text. Depending on how you're implementing you can accomplish this in many ways. You could wrap them in individual

tags, or  tags, or if it's a list consider  and

tags. This will allow you to apply the CSS to each line.

```css
p:before {
  content: "*";
}

p>br:after {
  content: "*";
}
```

```html
<p>test</p>
<p>test2</p>
<p>test3</p>
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants. He is asking for a way to add asterisks `*` by selecting raw text inside `p` without creating extra `p` elements.

Comment: so is it not possible using only CSS? I am not able to make changes to the HTML in this case.

Comment: @nylki No. With CSS, the only raw text that you can select is `::first-word` and `::first-line`. So either go with a different markup, which I suggest should be `ul` and set `list-style: none` with `ul li::before{ content: "*";}`. Or use JavaScript to parse the text content of this paragraph and dynamically add `*` before each new line text.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing one more ‘:’

So the css for this p would be something like:

```
p::before {
  content: "*";
}
p:before {
  content: "*";
}
```

Comment: This should not matter. CSS-Trick has an [article](https://css-tricks.com/to-double-colon-or-not-do-double-colon/) explaining why browsers understand both `:before` and `::before` as equal, although `::before` is semantically correct.

Comment: "*You are missing... `:`*" - no, "*As a rule, double colons (`::`) should be used instead of a single colon (`:`). [But]...most browsers support both syntaxes for the original pseudo-elements.*" ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)).